# Не работает aliases в postfix

Tags: postfix, alias

Postfix настроен только на отправку. И вроде везде советуют просто обновить aliases чтобы пересылать почту локального пользователя на внешний мейл, но у меня почему то не получается

postconf -n

```
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
append_dot_mydomain = no
biff = no
config_directory = /etc/postfix
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = ipv4
local_recipient_maps = $alias_maps
mailbox_size_limit = 0
masquerade_domains = mydomain.com
mydestination = mail.mydomain.com, localhost.localdomain, localhost
mydomain = mydomain.com
myhostname = mail.mydomain.com
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
myorigin = /etc/mailname
readme_directory = no
recipient_delimiter = +
relayhost =
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Debian/GNU)
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtpd_use_tls = yes
```

cat /etc/aliases

```
root: mymail@mydomain.com
```

Сохраняю `newaliases`

Но в логе все равно:

```
to=<root@mydomain.com>, relay=aspmx.l.google.com[64.233.166.26]:25,
delay=0.18, delays=0.03/0/0.07/0.09, dsn=5.1.1, status=bounced (host 
aspmx.l.google.com[64.233.166.26] said: 550-5.1.1 The email account that you 
tried to reach does not exist. Please try 550-5.1.1 double-checking the 
recipient's email address for typos or 550-5.1.1 unnecessary spaces. Learn more 
at 550 5.1.1  https://support.google.com/mail/answer/6596 wd2si11913770wjc.24 - 
gsmtp (in reply to RCPT TO command))
```

Comment: aspmx.l.google.com[64.233.166.26] said: 550-5.1.1 The email account that you 
tried to reach does not exist. Please try 550-5.1.1 double-checking the 
recipient's email address for typos

Тебе же ответил сервер, что такого ящика не существует: проверьте написание получателя на опечатки или лишние пробелы

Comment: Так я и о том же. Сделал алиас на другую почту, а оно все равно отправляет на рута.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`myorigin = /etc/mailname`

Из-за этого у тебя постфикс неправильно определяет локальных пользователей и не использует aliases. (default: $myhostname)

**UDP**

хотя похоже что это дефолтное значение для систем основанных на debian и оно работает, хотя и не документированно